# aurelia: binding and @observable not working

Tags: aurelia

I don't get why this "property changed" via @observable is not working, the stringValueChanged() method doesn't get called. What am I missing here? (The whole binding is not working here.)

currency-control.ts

```
import { bindable,  observable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CurrencyControl {

    @bindable
    value: number;

    @observable
    stringValue: string;

    constructor() {
    }

    valueChanged(newValue: number, oldValue: number) {
        alert('value changed');
    }

    stringValueChanged(newValue: string, oldValue: string) {
        alert('stringValueChanged changed');
    }
}
```

currency-control.html

```
<template>

    <require from="./currency-control.css"></require>

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">&euro;</div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" pattern="\d*" class="form-control" value.bind="stringValue" />
    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

My fault! In the component that uses the CurrencyControl I required the CurrencyControl's html:

```
<template>
    <require from="../currency-control/currency-control.html"></require>
```

instead of the component:

```
<template>
    <require from="../currency-control/currency-control"></require>
```